# How can I implement a repeating operation?

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I have the list:

```
l = 
  {{"d", "w", "x"}, {"a", "d"}, {"e", "h", "u", "d", "c", "q"}, 
   {"e", "c", "e", "a", "d", "e"}, {"s", "x", "r", "t", "v", "f"}, {"s"}, 
   {"c", "d", "e"}, {"s", "t", "y", "m"}, {"t", "d", "t", "u", "i", "q"}};
```

I want to select those elements that they are of length 6, so I evaluate

```
sizedl = Select[l, Length@# == 6 &]
```

and get

```
{{"e", "h", "u", "d", "c", "q"}, {"e", "c", "e", "a", "d", "e"}, 
 {"s","x", "r", "t", "v", "f"}, {"t", "d", "t", "u", "i", "q"}}
```

I next want to find the most common characters, pair them and capitalise them. I have the following function to do that.

```
replace = 
  With[
    {commonest = 
       Commonest[Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {2}] &, #], 1]][[1]]}, 
    # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ commonest, p___]} :> 
             {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], p}] &;

Alpha = NestList[replace, sizedl, 1]
```

The second part of Alpha gives:

```
{{"ED", "c", "h", "q", "u"}, {"ED", "a", "c", "e", "e"}, 
 {"s", "x", "r", "t", "v", "f"}, {"t", "d", "t", "u", "i", "q"}}
```

Now, in this new list I have two elements of 5 and two elements of size 6. I want to get rid of the ones that are size 5 and repeat the same procedure.

```
sizedl1 = Select[Alpha[[2]], Length @ # == 6 &];
Alpha = NestList[replace, sizedl1, 1];
```

I wonder how can I do this procedure for `t` times without repeating the code as above.

**Clarification: The output for t=3 should look like this:**

```
l = {{"d", "w", "x"}, {"a", "d"}, {"e", "h", "u", "d", "c", 
"q"}, {"e", "c", "e", "a", "d", "e"}, {"s", "x", "r", "t", "v", 
"f"}, {"s"}, {"c", "d", "e"}, {"s", "t", "y", "m"}, {"t", "d", 
"t", "u", "i", "q"}};

k = 2;
ClearAll[replace]
replace = 
  With[{commonest = 
      Commonest[
        Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {k}] &, #], 
         1]][[1]]}, # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ commonest,
         p___]} :> {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], p}] &;

m=1;
sized1 = Select[l, Length@# == 6 &];
a1 = NestList[replace, sizedl, m][[2]]

sized2 = Select[a1, Length@# == 6 &];
a2 = NestList[replace, sized2, m][[2]]

sized3 = Select[a2, Length@# == 6 &];
a3 = NestList[replace, sized3, m][[2]]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{{"ED", "c", "h", "q", "u"}, {"ED", "a", "c", "e", "e"}, {"s", "x", 
  "r", "t", "v", "f"}, {"t", "d", "t", "u", "i", "q"}}

{{"s", "x", "r", "t", "v", "f"}, {"TU", "d", "i", "q", "t"}}

{{"SX", "f", "r", "t", "v"}}
```

Comment: what is "replace" in your code?

Comment: Thank for the notice, I corrected it. replace it the function that does the replacement.

Comment: what about p and k in the replace function?

Comment: k is a number which indicates pairs and is equal to 2. Fixed it. and p is variable that indicates what shall be capitalised.

Comment: for the sake of example lets us take t=2. But in general I am dealing with a list that has 56000 elements and I want to apply the method for arbitrary t.

Comment: I posted something. I mean you need every step printed or the last one? and which one if the last?

Comment: Those three questions that I posted above really helped the OP to come up with his final question. I posted the answer and left before he posted his final question. Please wait some time before you push the downvote button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
replaceselect = Composition[replace, Select[Length @ # == 6 &]];
Rest @ NestWhileList[replaceselect , l, Length@# > 1 &]
```

> {{{"ED", "c", "h", "q", "u"}, {"ED", "a",  "c", 
>             "e", "e"}, {"s", "x", "r", "t", "v", "f"}, {"t", "d", "t", 
>          "u", "i", "q"}},
>    {{"s", "x", "r", "t", "v", "f"}, {"TU", "d", "i", 
>          "q", 
>             "t"}},
>   {{"SX", "f", "r", "t", "v"}}}

Comment: Such short and neat answer deserves a wow. I learnt a lot from you so far @kglr

Comment: Thank you for the accept and kind words @William.